# Deleting files from a list using shell

Tags: shell, applescript

I am a beginner with Applescript & Shell and am writing a script that at a certain point requires me to delete files that are listed within a .txt file. I have searched extensively on stackoverflow and was able to come up with the following command that I am running from within my Applescript...

```
do shell script "while read name; do
    rm -r \"$name"\
done < ~Documents/Script\\ Test/filelist.txt"
```

It seems to recognize and read the file, but I get an error that says this and I cannot figure out why:

> error "rm: ~/Documents/Script Test/filetodelete.rtf: No such file or directory" number 1

That said, I can navigate to that exact directory and verify that a file by that name with that extension does indeed exist. Can someone help shed some light on why this error might be occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo.  The path to the file is most probably `~/Documents`, not `~Documents` (which in Bash would be the home directory of a user whose account name is `Documents`).

If your shell is not Bash, it might not even support `~` for `$HOME`.

In the data file, you also cannot use `~` to refer to your home directory.  You could augment the loop with a simple substitution to support this:

```
while read -r file; do
    case $file in '~'*) file=$HOME${file#\~};; esac
    rm -r "$file"
done < ~/"Documents/Script Test/filelist.txt"
```

Notice also the use of `read -r` to avoid some pesky problems with the legacy default behavior of `read`.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct about the typo. I changed the error as it does say "rm: ~/Documents.." etc. 

I tried your variation using xargs -a but I get an error that says syntax error """ can't go after this identifier and it highlights the part between -a and "$

Comment: I updated the answer.  The `xargs` suggestion was removed because of your other tilde-related problem which rendered it unsuitable. Please refresh.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the update! I typed that code into the applescript editor the error I get says A "while" can't go here.

Comment: This is shell script; you need to wrap it inside AppleScript like you did with the original `while` loop in your example (or just keep it as a plain shell script; not sure what the possible benefit of the AppleScript wrapper might be).